# print json values from Ajax return

Tags: ajax, json

I don't know why my code doesn't print key and values out on screen. Alert message is "[Object Error]".

Could you please let me know how to print key and value paris on screen ?

index.html

```
<script>
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "image_finder.php",
       data: dataString,
       dataType: 'json',
       error:function(xhr,status,e){       
            alert('Error');
       },
       success: function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            alert(key); // problem 
         });


       },
       error:function(xhr, status, error) {
           alert(error);
       }

    });
</script>
```

json return

```
test{"tags":[{"cid":"14","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/","img_url":"http:\/\/static.naver.net\/www\/up\/2013\/0305\/mat_173330634c.jpg","img_name":"mat_173317134c.jpg","html":"<div id=\"hotspot-19\" class=\"hs-wrap hs-loading\">\r\n<img src=\"http:\/\/static.naver.net\/www\/up\/2013\/0305\/mat_173330634c.jpg\">\r\n<div class=\"hs-spot-object\" data-type=\"spot\" data-x=\"95\" data-y=\"64\" data-width=\"30\" data-height=\"30\" data-popup-position=\"left\" data-visible=\"visible\" data-tooltip-width=\"200\" data-tooltip-auto-width=\"true\">\r\nasdf\r\n<\/div>\r\n<div class=\"hs-spot-object\" data-type=\"spot\" data-x=\"168\" data-y=\"53\" data-width=\"30\" data-height=\"30\" data-popup-position=\"left\" data-visible=\"visible\" data-tooltip-width=\"200\" data-tooltip-auto-width=\"true\">\r\nrere\r\n<\/div>\r\n<\/div>\r\n","jscript":""}]}
```

Comment: if your "json return" is the data on success, most likely you want to do $.each() on the array, not on the data object, that would be $.each(data.tags, function(...) {...})

Answer (score -1):

You are returning invalid JSON from `image_finder.php` - look for a stray `print 'test';` or `echo 'test';` in `image_finder.php`.

You can use a service like http://jsonlint.com/ to validate the JSON being returned from your backend scripts. jQuery will error when the JSON is not valid and thats why the Alert message is an `[Object Error]`